# What is the default TokenLifespan of GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync and GenerateUserTokenAsync

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I have looked everywhere and cannot seem to find out for sure what the default for each of these is.

I also need to know if there is a way to set different Lifespans for each.
Thanks,

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The default is apparently 24 hours for any of the tokens. You can set it to a different value, but the same value will apply to all the tokens equally (`GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync`, `GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync` and `GenerateUserTokenAsync`).

Setting a new value is done by specifying, for example, `TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(3)` in the `ApplicationUserManager.Create` method in the App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs file:

```
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider =
                new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"))
                {
                    // Added custom code to set a different lifespan
                    TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(3)
                };
            ;
        }
        return manager;
```

Source: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity

Different lifespans for different types of tokens: Looks like pushed back to the next "major update", per this: https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/workitem/2228.

Comment: For me (Identity 2.2.1) the default is just 15 minutes. Setting the TokenLifespan worked for me.

Comment: @Smix I can't find evidence of that. The AspNetIdentity [project on github](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity) calls itself [version 2.1.0.0](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs#L45), and sets the default to `Timespan.FromDays(1)` [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin/DataProtectorTokenProvider.cs#L45). Taking [the latest from nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin/) and decompiling shows 2.2.3.11125, but the same lifespan.