# How to Set DataProtectorTokenProvider TokenLifetime in VB (Not c#)

Tags: owin, c#-to-vb.net

Looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31814795) which seems to address my need.

I need the VB.net (2015 preferred) syntax for this snippet. Specifically, Assign the TokenLifespan line.

```
if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
  {
     manager.UserTokenProvider = 
       new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"))
         {  
           // Added custom code to set a different lifespan                  
            TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(3)
         };
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried one or more of the many freely available online converters?   SO, is not a translation service.

Comment: Certainly. I have tried.
- http://converter.telerik.com/
- https://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator/

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have looked a day and never did find an answer to my C# to VB syntax question. No 'freely available online converter' was able handle the snippet. I tried perhaps a dozen or more. The ones that didn't error, skipped the property assignment.

In the end, I managed to code around the unknown syntax by instantiating an object and then assigning the property.

Here is the code I used to set the DataProtectorTokenProvider.TokenLifespan value:

```
If dataProtectionProvider IsNot Nothing Then
   Dim oTokenProvider As Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.DataProtectorTokenProvider(Of ApplicationUser)
   oTokenProvider = New DataProtectorTokenProvider(Of ApplicationUser)(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"))

   oTokenProvider.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15)

   manager.UserTokenProvider = oTokenProvider
End If
```

Perhaps this will help someone else down the road.
:-)